# Font-Awesome Icon not resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I have 3 font-awesome icons side-by-side in a dev tag. On mobile there were a bit too small. I put this in my code but this specific icon doesn't change size?

```
<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
```

And here's how they look:

[image]

CSS:

```
hover-info .fa .fa-heart {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to style it with css?

Comment: I did try in css maybe it might the way it's tag is in the css file. I even thought it was the container size and I changed the sizing for that as well, but it hasn't changed.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the container. Can you please post your 'css' attempt? ' so I can see if you have done it correctly

Comment: I added the piece of css to my question

Answer (score 5):

This is working in my browser:

```
.fa-heart {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

Maybe your reference to **'hover-info'** is causing the issue.

NOTE: your 'css' file has to be loaded after fontawesome.

Comment: I just found out what's was wrong. It was also in another css file in the project that I didn't know about and it was overriding it.

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Glad to hear that, and thank you for your support. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you don´t want to define a css class, is this way:

```
<font size="8"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </font>
```

Then it only remains to change the number of the font tag.
In my case this worked very well, I hope that in yours too.
Regards